# Validating mobile no. of users

Tags: javascript, validation

I have following function to validate mobile no.

```
 function validate()
{
var a = document.form.mobile_no.value; 
if(a=="")
{
alert("please Enter the Contact Number");
//document.form.mobile_no.focus();
return false;
}
if(isNaN(a))
{
alert("Enter the valid Mobile Number(Like : 9566137117)");
//document.form.mobile_no.focus();
return false;
}
if((a.length < 1) || (a.length > 10))
{
alert(" Your Mobile Number must be 1 to 10 Integers");
//document.form.mobile_no.select();
return false;
}
```

}

I have called the function from the form as:

```
<form action="" method="post"  onsubmit="validate()" id="teacher_form">
```

and the input from user is taken as:

But this process is not validating the result as it should. The entry is accepted without input validation.

Comment: Do you see any `alert()` before the submitting?

Comment: Why disallow `+91-9566137117`?

Comment: How do you submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression as

```
var regexMobile = /^[0-9]+$/;
var a = document.form.mobile_no.value; 
if (a.length < 10 || !a.match(regexMobile)) {
    alert("Enter valid 10 digit Mobile Number");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return false;` call in `onsubmit` handler. The code will be:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="validate(); return false;" id="teacher_form">
```

For better performance and multiple usage of the function, pass the form as an argument:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="validate(this); return false;" id="teacher_form">
```

The function will be something like:

```
function validate(x) {
    var a = x.mobile_no.value;
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/h9b8G/